# JavaScript auto re-size height

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been trying - and I'm at the point where I just don't know what to try anymore.

I'm trying to make my website's chat fill the entire page with this script

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        function setHeight() {
            windowHeight = $(window).innerHeight();
            $('ul').css('min-height', windowHeight);
        };
        setHeight();
        $(window).resize(function() {
            setHeight();
        });
    });
</script>
```

I'm using this script for my chat's `ul` tag, and it fits the height so the script works, but I'm trying to figure out how to make it fill about 95% of the page, so I still have room for the content below. (Send message, settings and emotes.)

I have a `div` tag around the entire chat, but setting that in the script doesn't affect the list of messages.

Any ideas to my struggle?

Comment: Your question is tagged with Javascript, but you are actually using jQuery Framework here. Do you accept jQuery/Javascript as well?

Answer (score 1):

dont bother with js/jquery, use css, pure css like this :

```
div {
    position: fixed!important;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

Comment: how does that work out in various versions of IE? ;)

Comment: @Schien: IE is retiring, and don't think many people using IE6 nowadays, if so, it's their fault. lol

Comment: What about IE7 and 8?

Comment: that's not a problem for these styles

Comment: I just don't want to miss out the opportunity to show the OP how to measure the screen client height and set the height of an element using clean, plain JavaScript instead of convoluted jQuery. He might find these pieces useful in other occasions when CSS doesn't cut it.

Comment: @schien: yes, sure, feel free to add it, ;) I was just trying provide a simple robust solution to the OP  lol

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83267/discussion-between-kevin-simple-and-schien).

Comment: This didn't work for me either. I have 2 divs, one for the container/wrapper and one for the chat. If I use the script or the css on the chat, it expands. If I use it on both the chat still expands to fit the whole page pushing the container away.

Comment: @Fugglet: use the css for the container, and add one style for you ul{height:95%}

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="container">
...
</div>
<script>
  var container=document.getElementById('container');
  var h=document.documentElement.clientHeight;
  container.style.height=h+'px';
</script>
```

Comment: This did the same for me. I have a div container, and a div for my chat. If I use one of these on my container, the div does not follow - and if I use it on both, the chat expands and there's no room for the container.